# Add a sand-box link on the ask question page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Is it possible to add a link to the ask question page suggesting users to first test in the current sandbox? This will probably help with visibility because most new users don't know that a sandbox exists and then the question gets edited to the annoyance of many people.

Comment: Perhaps a moderator could put it in the `How to ask` block.

Comment: I think for this to be practical, we will need a single sandbox. Otherwise the link has to be updated very frequently.

Comment: @hosch250 As far as I can tell, we don't have the power to do that.

Comment: @ace We have a couple of task to handle every time a we switch to a new sandbox anyway, if we could do it I'd be willing to look after it.

Comment: @dmckee I wasn't sure.  That would probably have to be someone from SE.

Comment: If they add support for customisation, they might consider auto-including links to questions which are [tag:featured] and have a per-site-configurable tag (in our case [tag:showcase]).

Comment: related: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/477/the-how-to-ask-page-is-misleading?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

The main problem I see with this is that the only people that will ever read the "How to Ask" message or the various sections of the "Ask Question" page are *new users*.

Since the sandbox is on meta, new users can't post to it (until they have at least 5? rep, I believe). I can see this leading to frustration.

I'm not saying that a link shouldn't be considered, but we may want to *also* encourage people to answer at least once before asking. This might not only alleviate the meta issue (most answers get *at least* 5 rep), but also cause them to see some other, *open* questions before posting one.

Of course, there's no way to force them to answer first, but a gentle nudge wouldn't hurt.

Comment: This is a great point, but we do get new users with 101 rep from other SE sites.  I'd actually bet that most new users are already on the SE network.

Comment: @NotthatCharles Agreed. Like I said, a link isn't out of the question, but I'd still encourage users that are new *here* to look around at other questions and maybe throw an answer out there. This site is just a *bit* different than your typical SE site. Either way, I imagine that users from other SE sites are less likely to read the "how to ask" tips than truly new people (not that I think most completely new users read it anyway), because they *think* they already know how to ask a question on SE.

Answer (score 0):

## Proposal

1. A moderator puts a link to the [sandbox](/questions/tagged/sandbox) meta tag in the How to Ask box.
2. We then change the tag summary to give folks instructions on what to do.
3. Finally, close retired Sandboxes with no new activity using a reasonable close reason that keeps them out of views.